# ClassNotFoundException in jdbc program

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a mysql database using JDBC, but I am getting the ClassNotFoundException. How do I solve it? Below, is my code :

```
package PkgJDBC;

import java.sql.*;  

class MysqlCon {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://172.16.7.19:3306/sb2016","sb2016","rspl123#");  

            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from intern1_student");

            while(rs.next())  
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  

            con.close();  
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Most likely the MySQL driver is not on your classpath.

Comment: How are you running this program?

Comment: I also tried adding the required jar file "com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar", still I am getting the same exception

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the MySQL Connector/J JAR file to your CLASSPATH.

The `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` line has been obsolete since 2007.